# Bluebird promises freeze when using Sinon's fake timer

Tags: node.js, sinon, bluebird

The following test freezes when used with Sinon's fake timers and Bluebird.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

describe('failing test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });
  afterEach(function() {
    this.clock.restore();
  });
  it('test', function(done) {
    Promise.delay(1000).then(function(){
        done(); //This never gets called     
    });
  });
});
```

I am using Mocha (v2.2.5) with Bluebird (v2.9.33) and Sinon (v1.15.3).

I tried the suggestions offered in some discussions in Bluebird and Sinon but I couldn't make this work. This seems to be an issue with the way Sinon stubs setImmediate but other than that I have no clue how to resolve this.

Comment: Use Promise.setScheduler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to step the fake timer manually like so:

```
describe('failing test', function() {
  it('test', function(done) {
    Promise.delay(1000).then(function(){
        done(); //This never gets called     
    });
    //
    // ADVANCE THE CLOCK:
    //
    this.clock.tick(1000);
  });
});
```

Btw, mocha has built-in support for promises, so an even better way to do this would be to `return` your promise:

```
describe('failing test', function() {
  it('test', function() { // No more "done" callback
    var p = Promise.delay(1000).then(function(){
        console.log('done'); 
    });
    this.clock.tick(1000);
    return p; // Return the promise instead - mocha will take of the async magic goodness!
  });
});
```

From my experience, mixing promises and the `done` callback style leads to all sorts of trouble and hard to track errors. When using promises, try to stick with returning, and have a look at a library such as [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised). I promise you it'll make your tests much more readable!

Comment: Thanks! However, I want to avoid to step the timer as this is not needed by my test. I just need to do this because of incompatibilities between two libraries and it doesn't sound right! 
PS: Thanks for your suggestion about how to handle promises with Mocha.

Comment: If you want to use a fake timer and also do Promise.delay(), you have no other option than to step the timer manually. That's the whole point of the fake timers, actually - to give you control over the progression of time.

Comment: I agree. In this test case though all I want to do is freeze the time rather than control its progression. That's why stepping the timer feels like an overkill. What I want to do was possible before updating those libraries to the newest versions and that's why I wanted to find out if it still possible. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: The fact the first solution works is implementation detail, and we might break it in the future in bluebird. It's an optimization to not run the `then` in a deferred way since a timer is already asynchronous. This will also cause a race condition. The second (promise) alternative works.

Answer (score 2):

### Best practices:

Don't use fake timers, they can cause weird concurrency issues because they synchronously call deferred functions - thus changing execution. Instead use Mocha's built in promises support as:

```
describe('failing test', function() {
    it('test', function(){ 
        return Promise.delay(1000); // return the promise here, no `done`
    });
```

### But if you must

Please don't, but you can tell bluebird to run its then callbacks synchronously, I strongly recommend against this and it *will* cause timing issues in your app:

```
Promise.setScheduler(function(fn){
    return fn();
});
```

Comment: I believe your advice is entirely wrong. First of all, tests with real time have exactly same timing issues (as you can't really predict how fast will the code be executed on production machine), second - make tests much, much slower. I agree that since `sinon` timers (currently `lolex`) are synchronous, they really aren't the best possible implementation. Still, you can use asynchronous libraries (like `zurvan` for node.js - disclaimer: I'm its author). Second, changing scheduler won't change anything, as by default `setImmediate` is used, which isn't time-dependent.

Comment: You can run all tests in parallel if you're concerned about them being slow, you can typically get north of 10K concurrent tests if you write your code correctly. As for timing issues it won't _eliminate_ existing timing issues, but it won't cause any new ones - using synchronous fake timers will most definitely cause timing issues (it's such a huge issue that jQuery is rewriting their promises for 3.0 breaking half the internet in the process) - effectively introducing a race condition. Introducing a race condition just for testing is never good.

Comment: Also, `Promise.setScheduler` _will_ in fact run callbacks without calling setImmediate, if you notice it does anything different please file a bug report so I can fix it - it's definitely not the behavior we mean for `setScheduler` to have in bluebird, if you set the scheduler to run the callbacks synchronously it will do so..

Comment: as far as I know, `setScheduler` simply uses passed function as a way of - notabene - scheduling tasks after promise resolution/rejection. By default it's `setImmediate/process.nextTick/setTimeout(0)/MutationObserver`, but you can of course change it to anything you want, including ignoring functions.

Comment: @TomaszLewowski right, and you can also change it to resolve synchronously - promises run all their `then` callbacks after a turn (using a trampoline, but effectively you can think about it like a `setImmediate`, native promises do it after all `nextTick`s and before any `setImmediate`s, bluebird uses setImmediate most likely). this behavior by promises guards against race conditions (a function being sometimes sync and sometimes async). Using `setScheduler` with just calling a function changes that to violate Promises/A+, but also be able to write trivial sync promise tests.

Comment: Of course I agree that executing timeouts synchronously (e.g. synchronous fake timers) will cause a lot of mess in flow - however, parallel execution is not that easy in bigger systems, especially ones that are using shared resources - because it's really a common problem that you simply exchange timing problems into more timing problems (that's good - they're real) _and_ synchronization problems (that might be bad - often test environment is put to artificial state, and executing multiple testcases may result in unexpected output)

Comment: Right, but if you write your tests in an isolated way (without global state) you _can_ execute them in parallel (or at least concurrently) without causing those issues. I worked with a 15K tests test suite full of async tests that ran in under a minute with mocha syntax. Essentially there is very little overhead by having an async test if you're not actually waiting for anything because things run concurrently and isolated from each other.

Comment: Sure, if you have the comfort of set of independent testcases and modules without global (in whatever way) dependencies, then you can of course run them in parallel and not care about real time delays, assuming you only have actions with very short (~seconds) timers (e.g. no stuff like "if connection is not reestablished after an hour from break, notify administrator") - otherwise you have to fake time somehow anyway

Comment: I don't understand, do adversarial people write your test cases? Can't you just _decide_ to scope state to a `describe` instead of making it global? You can't test flows like "if connection not reestablished after an hour from break, notify administrator" reliably using node timers anyway - you'd spawn a VM and play with its time or scheduling instead and that's not log code should probably have in the first place. Even if it is and you insist on writing it this way - you can still very easily test it - mock Promise.delay directly to expose a deferred you manually resolve. Simple as pie.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91665/discussion-between-tomasz-lewowski-and-benjamin-gruenbaum).

Comment: Yeah, I'm running into all sorts of weird concurrency issues with using Sinon's fake timers. However, I want to test some code that recurs after a set period, and I can't have my code sit for that period in time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404766/how-to-test-a-recursively-called-function-in-nodejs So I need some way to step the clock forward without having Sinon blow up all the things.