# How to test a recursively called function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, recursion, mocha.js

I have a recurring function written in ES6/7 which is transpiled by babel. I have a recurring function created that checks if there is a user document, using mongoose.

```
// Keep checking if there is a user, if there is let execution continue
export async function checkIfUserExists(){
  let user = await User.findOneAsync({});
  // if there is no user delay one minute and check again
  if(user === null){
    await delay(1000 * 60 * 1)
    return checkIfUserExists()
  } else {
    // otherwise, if there a user, let the execution move on
    return true
  }
}
```

If there is no user I am using the `delay` library to delay execution for a minute upon which the function is called recursively.

This allows the halting of execution of the overall function until a user is found:

```
async function overallFunction(){
  await checkIfUserExists()
  // more logic
}
```

The else branch is very easy to generate tests for. How do I create a test for the if branch that verifies the recursion is working properly?

At the moment I have replaced the delay method with proxyquire during testing, subbing it for a custom delay function that just returns a value. At that point I can change the code to look like this:

```
// Keep checking if there is a user, if there is let execution continue
export async function checkIfUserExists(){
  let user = await User.findOneAsync({});
  // if there is no user delay one minute and check again
  if(user === null){
    let testing = await delay(1000 * 60 * 1)
    if (testing) return false
    return checkIfUserExists()
  } else {
    // otherwise, if there a user, let the execution move on
    return 
  }
}
```

Issue there is that the source code is being changed to accommodate for the test. Is there a better, cleaner solution?

Comment: Five years on and none of the answers have been marked as accepted. Did any help you out on this?

Answer (score 2):

I've written an example of how you could test your recursively called function here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/qppprz20/

This test makes use of the [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) javascript test library. You can set-up the behaviour of the stub on the nth call, hence you can simulate when no user is returned and then subsequently when a user is returned e.g.

```
// Stub the method behaviour using Sinon javascript framework
var user = new User();
var userStub = sinon.stub(user, 'findOneAsync');
userStub.onFirstCall().returns(null);
userStub.onSecondCall().returns({});
```

Hence onFirstCall simulates the first call and onSecondCall the recursive call.

Note that in the full example I've simplified checkIfUserExists, but the same test premise will apply for your full method. Also note that you would additionally have to stub your delay method.

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries that can be used for testing time-related events. As far as I know the most common solution is Lolex - https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex, earlier part of Sinon project. The problem with Lolex is that it forwards the timers synchronously, thus ignoring events such as native node promises or `process.nextTick` (although it does fake `setImmediate` properly) - therefore you can get into some nasty issues. Be careful about external libraries - for example, `bluebird` caches the initial `setImmediate`, so you need to handle it somehow manually.

A different choice is Zurvan - https://github.com/Lewerow/zurvan (disclaimer: I wrote it). It's a bit harder to tackle than Lolex, since it uses promises heavily, but behaves properly in presence of microqueued tasks (`process.nextTick`, native `Promise`) and has a built-in compatibility option for bluebird.

Both libraries allow you to expire time-related events on arbirary length and override also `Date` instances (zurvan overrides `process.uptime` and `process.hrtime` as well). Neither of them is safe to use if you perform actual async IO in tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wanted to use a recursive solution instead of an iterative solution - but it might be easier to write it iteratively if for no other reason than so you don't blow the stack:

```
  do{
  let user = await User.findOneAsync({});
  // if there is no user delay one minute and check again
  if(user === null){
    await delay(1000 * 60 * 1);
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
  }while (!user);
```

Haven't tested or run this through an interpreter - but you get the idea.

Then in your testing mode - just provide a test user.  Since you'll probably need to write tests that use a reference to the user anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I'm testing this, how do I test the conditional branch that is triggered if there is no user present. If I'm using Mocha the test will just timeout eventually because it is continuing to call itself.

Comment: Then you explicitly unset the user before running the tests, then start running the tests, wait a bit and then set the user.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, that's what I was thinking. What if the delay is super long though (5 minutes - 1 hour). There's a Sinon helper method to 'jump forward' in time isn't there?